# WSO2 IS SAML SSO Account locked claim do not working

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

Account Locked claim works fine for basic authenticator, but for Facebook and Google identity providers I still can login into my application for locked users.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Account Locked claim is a local claim and can only be used for local users (users who are in a configured userstore). For federated users you may try [associating user accounts](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Associating+User+Accounts) and setting associated local user account's Account Locked claim.